# How can I have a JButton update for all clients connected to a server?

Tags: java, swing, server, client, jbutton

I have a java project on which I am working on where I created a multiplayer game of Ludo (the code is disgusting, but it works). The game connects to a server, and based on local client input (which is a button), the game will then move that Ludo game figurine to the location it needs to be for all clients. This works fine. Here is the code for that (within the run() method of my thread which listens for server output):

```
switch(temp_currentTurn) {
      case 0:
         if(temp_greenCounter == 1){
            green1.setBounds(greenArrX.get(currX), greenArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_greenCounter == 2){
            green2.setBounds(greenArrX.get(currX), greenArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_greenCounter == 3){
            green3.setBounds(greenArrX.get(currX), greenArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_greenCounter == 4){
            green4.setBounds(greenArrX.get(currX), greenArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         break;
      case 1:
         if(temp_yellowCounter == 1){
            yellow1.setBounds(yellowArrX.get(currX), yellowArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_yellowCounter == 2){
            yellow2.setBounds(yellowArrX.get(currX), yellowArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_yellowCounter == 3){
            yellow3.setBounds(yellowArrX.get(currX), yellowArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_yellowCounter == 4){
            yellow4.setBounds(yellowArrX.get(currX), yellowArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         break;
      case 2:
         if(temp_redCounter == 1){
            red1.setBounds(redArrX.get(currX), redArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_redCounter == 2){
            red2.setBounds(redArrX.get(currX), redArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_redCounter == 3){
            red3.setBounds(redArrX.get(currX), redArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_redCounter == 4){
            red4.setBounds(redArrX.get(currX), redArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         break;
      case 3:
         if(temp_blueCounter == 1){
            blue1.setBounds(blueArrX.get(currX), blueArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_blueCounter == 2){
            blue2.setBounds(blueArrX.get(currX), blueArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_blueCounter == 3){
            blue3.setBounds(blueArrX.get(currX), blueArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         if(temp_blueCounter == 4){
            blue4.setBounds(blueArrX.get(currX), blueArrY.get(currY), size.width, size.height);
         }
         break;
   }
   repaint();
```

The figurine is set based on the switch statement (whose turn it is) and the figurine is moved based on the X and Y coordinate it receives. However, for each player, when a button is clicked, the buttons only update locally, like so:

```
greenDie.setEnabled(false);
yellowDie.setEnabled(true);
```

Something similar is for the other buttons, just with added logic which works fine locally for how many players are playing.

My question is, I have tried to put that same logic in the run part of my code but it does not update the buttons for each player. How can I update the buttons for each player that is connected, and not just locally?

Comment: Where is the actual main game model being held? On each client or on the server? It should be on the server, and the clients simply pass requests to the server that the model should be changed. Once changed, the server should send updated data to all the models so that their graphical representation of the model (their local view) can be properly updated.

Comment: Unfortuneately, for whatevere reason, it was requested from us to keep the logic on the client side. I do not know why. But from what I understand, based on the current turn that is sent to the server as well, the button changes should happen there? If I understood you correclty?

Comment: The model on all clients must be tied together somehow, and that must be through the server. The server must notify all the clients of state changes, and your code will need to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a problem with the request to keep all the logic locally.

The server can act as a storage facility only. Think of it as a separate class, let's call it Server.java.

This class has the attribute button, and 2 methods, getButton() and setButton(Button button).

A player, upon updating their button locally, will now call the setButton(localPlayerButton) on the Server.java. All of the other players will then set their localPlayerButton value to getButton() called on the Server.java, so that they are all updated.

All the logic of the game still happens client side, you're just using the server for storage. Alternatively, you could use a database to store values for the button.